# url encoding is wrong but works

Tags: html, image, url, urlencode, src

Why the src attribute of an image in html is:

https://www.ft.com/__origami/service/image/v2/images/raw/http%3A%2F%2Fprod-upp-image-read.ft.com%2Fafe24c11-a86d-4444-bd64-1c2f4e4e3a54?source=next&fit=scale-down&compression=best&width=210 210w, https://www.ft.com/__origami/service/image/v2/images/raw/http%3A%2F%2Fprod-upp-image-read.ft.com%2Fafe24c11-a86d-4444-bd64-1c2f4e4e3a54?source=next&fit=scale-down&compression=best&width=150 150w

& and = are not encoded but they should be $;amp or something. Why is that?

Comment: Ampersand and equal signs are perfectly legal in a URL. You may be thinking of how an ampersand gets escaped in XHTML with `&amp;`

Answer (score 0):

"encoding" in URL is that stuff with %20 (or shortened with +) for space, that escaping with `&` is XML (and all derivates like SGML, HTML, XHTML, XSLT, …). As `&` is used for escaping other things, it needs to be escaped there as well, with `&amp;`. That is used e.g. in XML files when there is a URL included.

be aware there are different styles of url encoding; a simple  playground for that is php which has [urlencode](http://php.net/urlencode) and [rawurlencode](http://php.net/rawurlencode) besides the same for decoding as functions.

The URL within HTML is encoded properly with & as a separator for parameters
after the first parameter. You can look this up in the RFCs (e.g. [RFC 2396, section 3.3 following](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2396#page-14)). If you wanted to say "Barnes and Noble" then it would be escaped withing the Text as `Barnes &amp; Noble`. But in the URL it stands as such. Just in cases like XML processed by XSLT you'd again need to escape it.

So for attributes like `href` ad `src` imagine the content of that just is parsed differently and as such different rules apply.

Comment: so why & are not escaped with &;amp here?

Comment: Basically the URL is an URL, not HTML. That's why. Although this can be tricky in edge cases still.